# Two text boxes one with limited number of characters other text box containing remaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, contenteditable

I want to make two  text boxes such that if one writes some text 
First 50 characters  should be in first text box
 what ever entered next should go to 
the next text box

in jquery or Javascript[image]

The code looks something like this

> var content_id = 'editable_div';
>       max = 50;

```
//binding keyup/down events on the contenteditable div
$('#'+content_id).keyup(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });
$('#'+content_id).keydown(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });

function check_charcount(content_id, max, e)
{   
    if(e.which != 50 && $('#'+content_id).text().length > max)
    {
       //the remaining part focusing the mouse on to the next div let the id of the  next editable div be  next

        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is a place to ask questions, not somewhere to record your wish list. Show that you've at least attempted to build this system, and we'll try to help fix it. But right now you're just another "gimme the codez" freeloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the user is typing.   http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/fwU8D/

```
$("textarea:eq(0)").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length>=10){ //for test: 10
          var str  =$(this).val();
          var length = str.length;
          $("textarea:eq(0)").val(str.slice(0,10));
          $("textarea:eq(1)").val($("textarea:eq(1)").val()    
                                  +str.slice(10,length));

    }
});
$("textarea:eq(0)").keydown(function(){
   if($(this).val().length>=10){//for test: 10              
          var str  =$(this).val();
          var length = str.length;
          $("textarea:eq(0)").val(str.slice(0,10));
          $("textarea:eq(1)").val($("textarea:eq(1)").val()    
                                  +str.slice(10,length));

    }
});
$("textarea:eq(0)").change(function(){
   if($(this).val().length>=10){//for test: 10
          var str  =$(this).val();
          var length = str.length;
          $("textarea:eq(0)").val(str.slice(0,10));
          $("textarea:eq(1)").val(str.slice(10,length));
          $(this).attr("readonly","readonly");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="first"></textarea>
<textarea id="second"></textarea>
```

Comment: Awesome @insertusernamehere 1.what if the user pastes the text 2.He cant edit text if text greater than 50

Comment: for problem 2. I add $(this).attr("readonly","readonly"); into code

Comment: @Shih-EnChou 2.User cant edit the text in the first box because the text is greater than 50  I mean if we try to focus the mouse on the first box and try to edit it will be edited in the second box